# convert vector with multiple attributes to multiple rasters

Tags: qgis, raster, vector

I have a vector polygon feature with multiple attributes/fields. Ultimately, I want to convert it to a raster 'stack,' whereby each of the attributes/fields will be a different band of the raster feature. What is the best way to do this in as few steps as possible?
platforms: QGIS 1.8 lisboa.

Comment: Please edit your post to include what software suite you want to use.

Comment: In other words multiple input fields?